# exception for non existing parameter in FLASK

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have a form that sends parameters.
In my form I have a checkbox.
If my checkbox is not checked then I will not get any parameters.

If in my module I have :

```
var = request.form['mycheckbox']
```

and if my checkbox is not checked (the parameter is not passed)

Then in debug mode I get the error message :

> Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server
>   could not understand.

Nothing tells me about what the error is.

I prevented the exception by using :

```
    try:
        var=request.form['checkbox']
    except:
        var=None
```

But can I not change the behavior of how Flask handles this case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this is hidden in the flask documentation here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.trap_http_exception

I'm not sure why this behaviour isn't changed for debugging mode, but to get Flask to catch the BadRequestKeyError exceptions from werkzeug, you need to run something like this on your application object:

```
app.config['TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS'] = True
```

Comment: I filed https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/382 to see if this can be made the default when debugging is enabled.

Comment: I must say, this is truly disappointing behavior that had me baffled at why flask didn't wanna talk to me, when I'm showing it so much love. Thanks for opening ticket and your answer

Answer (score 15):

```
var = request.form.get('checkbox')
```

This will return `None` if the parameter is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue during validation of single boolean field.

I solved it by using `remember = form.rememberme.data` instead of `request.form['remember_me']`