# How to find package for a particular class in python

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to python and I keep hitting the same old problem over and over again.  How do I find out which packages I'm meant to use to import things for python? I see some brilliant code in a forum that will solve a particular problem but the snippet doesn't include the packages you need.  A quick Google will turn up more snippets but still not the package so I can't use that solution.

My most recent problem in this area is handling a BadRequestKeyError exception for working with the flask webframework.  I found out the exception type using the eclipse debugger so I did the following:

```
try:   
    # Some code 
exception BadRequestKeyError as keyError:   
    # Handling Code
```

Now I'm getting import errors on that exception so I tried looking in flask.exceptions because a straight import x did not work (so I need from y.z import x). I could not find anything.  I tried looking online and found no reference to the package I need.  Is there some way, or resource perhaps, that every python programmer knows about that I don't?  Am I missing something or is this a common problem?

Comment: seems this is a known issue - [exception for non existing parameter in FLASK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896473/exception-for-non-existing-parameter-in-flask)

Comment: `from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequestKeyError`

Comment: It's a wider problem for me then just this case, I have encountered instances of seeing code that I'd like to use but because the packages were never mentioned I can't use it. I just discovered that if I already have an instance of the object (as in this case) I can call .__module__ on it to get the package I need to import, which solves half of my problem.

Comment: yeah that's a good way to figure it out. Till now i was using grep to search in my folders(site-packages for example), for example: `grep -nr "BadRequestKeyError" --color .`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some code search engine to find it, for example:

http://code.ohloh.net/search?s=BadRequestKeyError%20&browser=Default